# How to convert hard coded array to Observable<T> in angular 6

Tags: arrays, angular, observable, angular6

How can you convert an array to an observable array in angular 6.
I am trying to return an observable while having an array. I'm doing this so that instead of an HTTP request I can return hard-coded data.

I have the following interface:

```
export interface IProduct {
  productId: number;
  productName: string;
  productCode: string;
  releaseDate: string;
  description: string;
  price: number;
  starRating: number;
  imageUrl: string;
}
```

Then I have this service:

```
export class ProductService {

  products: IProduct[];

  getProducts(): Observable<IProduct[]> {
    this.products = [
      {
        'productId': 2,
        'productName': 'Black cat',
        'productCode': 'GDN-001',
        'releaseDate': 'March 18, 2018',
        'description': 'Can punch peoples faces.',
        'price': 32.00,
        'starRating': 5,
        'imageUrl': 'https://placekitten.com/400/420'
      },
      {
        'productId': 3,
        'productName': 'T Cat',
        'productCode': 'GDN-002',
        'releaseDate': 'March 18, 2018',
        'description': 'Can shoot guns.',
        'price': 32.00,
        'starRating': 2.2,
        'imageUrl': 'https://placekitten.com/400/420'
      }
    ];

    //paste here how to return the array to observable

  }
}
```

Comment: You can use `of(this.products)`. It's imported from `rxjs`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use the `of` operator

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';


return of(this.products);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `from`

```
import { from } 'rxjs'

export class ProductService {

  products: IProduct[];

  getProducts(): Observable < IProduct[] > {
    this.products = [{...}, {...}];
    return from(this.products);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Rxjs 5 or earlier:

You can just use

```
return Observable.of(this.products);
```

make sure to import,

```
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `of` which will return `Observable` of argument that `of` has gotten. Import it from `import { of } from 'rxjs';`

```
return of(this.products);
```